# Magento - Make a copy of history.phtml and use it in my own way

Tags: magento

I’m looking to find a way to copy the page history that we can access from My account/My orders which is available on this directory template/sales/order/history.phtml and use its content on my own way without affecting the original one. I’ve been trying many ways, as copying the whole directory and editing the Xml files related to it in order to setup up the right path and make it work, unfortunately it was a failure. I would like to know if you could give me a solution for this.
thx.

Comment: To confirm you want just a different version of the .phtml of do you want to access the functions within that .phtml file (such as getOrderHistory())??

Comment: Thx a lot for your prompt answer. this is the case. I want to keep the original version of history.phtml for the section My orders/History, and copy the same file edit it and use it in my own module

Comment: Alan, at the same time I'd like also to use function such as getOrderHistory() in another file. thx a lot

Answer (score 2):

To use the functions of a block inside another .phtml I'm quite sure you can use getBlock

```
$blockFunctions = $this->getLayout()->getBlock('sales/order_history');
$order = $blockFunctions->getOrderHistory();
```

And to add a block in your custom module you'll need to create a .xml file for your block and add it to your template, you'll also have to add the actual .phtml file. Take a look at the moduleCreator (http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/danieln/extension/1108/modulecreator) this handles most of this quite well.

This is by no means througher its just a rough guide.

Comment: Thx a lot Alan, but do you know how to copy the page history.phtml and rename it and be able to edit it and make it work. I've tried that but when I call my page history_2.phtml I get a 404 Not found. do you know what's the right thing to do. please

Comment: As said you need to build a layout file and you also need a controller and a block file (it isn't just a case of copy and paste then visit in the URL) if you build a module with module creator like suggested it will give you a .phtml file with the name of your module, you can then copy and paste the code from history.phtml into your own. (Bearing in mind if you use any of the 'Block functions' you'll need to create the block as above.

Comment: Thank you Alan, I've created a module before. but now i'm using the module creator, I followed all the steps but I have this error now :Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE, expecting T_FUNCTION. Do you know where the problem comes from please? thank you again

Comment: is the error with the moduleCreator or with Magento? Either way you should try just downloading MC and installing it in another folder, this will give you a 'boilerplate' module you can edit before adding to your Magento /app folder.

Comment: the error is with Magento. the MC did the work. everything is setup properly

Comment: Alan, any suggestion. please?

Comment: Without seeing an error file I wouldn't be able to tell were this error comes from.